# Boto3 S3 Resource Retry Strategy Implementation

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I was working with boto3 in Python to interact with an S3 bucket that I created. Currently I am using the Bucket and Object resources for my interactions with S3, such as:
`s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name).Object(key=object_key).put()`

I was taking a look at how I could potentially implement a basic retry strategy for failed put attempts when I came across this [documentation page](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/retries.html) that talks about a built-in retry strategy with boto3.

I wanted to ask, does this retry strategy apply to using the resources rather than clients in boto3, and if not how I could go about implementing a similar retry strategy. Thanks!